# How can I get Windows 7 to display the "Insert Unicode control character" menu in Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, unicode, i18n, arabic

I'm trying to help a translator l10n our application into Arabic and need to find a way for her to easily enter right-to-left and left-to-right Unicode characters in Google Chrome on Windows 7 (I'm not a Windows user BTW, so for both our sakes I'm looking for a simple solution).

My googling brought me to [this blog post](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2009/08/ime-vista-start-menu-annoyances.html) where a user is complaining about a bunch of unwanted menus items being displayed in Vista.

[image: Unicode menus]

I want that menu!

I've tried locating the "Extend text services to all programs" option in "Text Services and Input languages in Regional options" as mentioned by a commenter but is doesn't appear anywhere that I can see.

Comment: AFAIK those menu options appear in the standard textbox control in Vista+ by default, but apps such as Firefox or Chrome that do not use the default textbox control or override its context menu with their own custom options will not have them obviously.